# I want to add buttons next to the option button in Tablets

Tags: android

I want to add some buttons next to the system option menu , how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
[action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

[Icon of Action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html)

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/save_button"
          android:title="i"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```